# ReSharper C++ dotSettings file for popular coding standards

Tags: resharper-c++

Are there any ReSharper `.dotSettings` files available for popular coding standards (e.g. [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespace_Names) or [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586))?

I'm a bit surprised that I can't seem to find any of these. I would expect to find several `.dotSettings` files that implement various existing popular coding standards.

Comment: Did you find any since you posted this? I've looked around and still can't find any so figured it was worth a shot asking if you had. Thanks.

Comment: Not yet, but haven't looked.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. The plan is for ReSharper C++ to have builtin sets of code formatting preferences that correspond to popular coding standards (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-20168).